# Проблема со сложным sql-запросом

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Здравствуйте! Функция получает параметр через адресную строку и делает выборку из БД. Если запрос ввожу с конкретными цифрами в phpmyadmin, то запрос выводит то, что нужно. А функция возвращает пустой массив:

```
function article_block($category){
    try {
        $dsn = sprintf('mysql:host=%s;dbname=%s;charset=utf8', HOST, DB);
        $pdo = new PDO($dsn, USER, PASS);
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "<p>Запрос на выборку данных из бызы не прошёл. Напишите об этом администратору <a href='mailto:admin@torawhite.ru'>admin@torawhite.ru</a>.</p><br>ERROR: " . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }

    $sql = '(SELECT article_id, article_cat_id, article_par_id, article_title, article_img, article_author, article_author_card, article_description, article_date, article_views FROM articles WHERE article_cat_id = :cat)
            UNION
            (SELECT article_id, article_cat_id, article_par_id, article_title, article_img, article_author, article_author_card, article_description, article_date, article_views FROM articles WHERE article_cat_id IN
            (
                SELECT cat_id FROM magazine_left_sidebar WHERE parent_id = :cat
            ))';


    $data = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $data->bindValue (':cat', $category);
    $data->execute();
    $article_block = $data->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $article_block;
}
```

Не могу понять, в чём дело...

Comment: я бы попробовал убрать лишние скобки и сделать два параметра, чем черт не шутит

Comment: Если используется bindValue - то желательно указывать тип связываемого значения - `$data->bindValue (':cat', $category, PDO::PARAM_INT);`

А вообще можно исключить bindValue: `$data->execute(array(":cat"=>$category));`

И что если после `$data->execute` сделать `var_dump($data)` - посмотреть, что там наизвлекалось?

Comment: @Etki, заработало только так: $data->bindValue (':cat', (int)$category, PDO::PARAM_INT); Но работает некорректно - при любом параметре извлекает одно и то же. Если запрос скопировать напрямую в phpmyadmin, то всё работает отлично

Comment: @boris_U , не работает,к сожалению. В ту же функцию принудительно ставлю значение - 1, например, всё работает! Что не так-то((

Comment: Разобрался $category = $_GET['category']; Не думал, что так важно, как оказалось...

Answer (score 1):

Из документации:

> " Вы должны подбирать уникальные имена псевдопеременных для каждого
>   значение, которое необходимо передавать в запрос при вызове
>   PDOStatement::execute(). "Нельзя использовать одну псевдопеременную в
>   запросе больше одного раза, если только не включен режим эмуляции.
>
> Замечание: Маркеры параметров представляют из себя только
>   непосредственно данные. Ни часть данных, ни специальные слова, ни
>   идентификаторы, никакая другая часть запроса не могут быть переданы
>   через параметры. Например, вы не можете привязать несколько значений к
>   одному параметру для SQL выражения IN()."